# Angular Material Scroller has wrong height inside a Tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Angular Material and have a page with a few full size tabs.  Inside these tabs are custom components using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport.  On the initially active tab, everything works great.  But when I switch to another tab, the scroll-viewport shows only a few items, depending on the size of the buffer, because the calculated viewport size is apparently 0.

If I call "`checkViewportSize()`", the size is correctly re-calculated and all required items are shown.

The problem now is to find the best place to call this function.  For testing purpose I did this via `window.setInterval()`, but that is definitely not a proper solution.

Is there any event / lifecycle-hook / ..., when a component becomes visible, which can be used?

Has anyone ever experienced the same issue?  What was the solution?

Comment: If the components inside the tabs rely on the DOM calculations, you should make your tabs lazily load the contents. This should fix your issues without modifying your actual component, which is probably the way to go. See the docs [here](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading).

Comment: Great, thanks.  Didn't noticed that in the docs before.  It solved my issue.